# How to detect new window in watIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I am using WatIn. I need to get the OuterHtml from the new window that opens when I click on the link.

I tried to find the new popup but i think it's working only from the popup in the same window, but I'm getting a new window.

How can i found the new window that my link opens?

```
using (IE browser = new IE("https://login.com"))
{
    try
    {
        if (linkExist) browser.Image(Find.ById("inputSend")).Click();
            browser.WaitForComplete();
            linkExist = false;

            //This not working
            var poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl("https://login.123.com"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        successful = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get a new window by clicking a link, then use ClickNoWait method for the link. Since Click triggers a wait for call to finish, which will internally checks for the browser state and might throw exception. Please use the below code and check.

```
using (IE browser = new IE("https://login.com"))
{
try
{
    if (linkExist) browser.Image(Find.ById("inputSend")).ClickNoWait();            
        linkExist = false;

        IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(url => url.Contains("https://login.123.com")));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    successful = false;
}
```

}

Make sure the targeted URL string is proper in the Attach TO method.